# How make the leaflet map display like the corona virus this when we click on cluster

Tags: leaflet

[image]

How we can display like the above image when user click on cluster of number on leaflet map.

Comment: See the "spiral" strategy for markercluster spiderifying, at https://github.com/adammertel/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.PlacementStrategies

Comment: thanks you for the link